# High CPU usage on GORM

Tags: go, cpu, go-gorm

We have suspicious issue on our function with gorm context

```
func (*OrderRepositoryImpl) FindByIdAndUserWithTransaction(tx *gorm.DB, id int, userID string) (models.Order, error) {
    order := models.Order{}

    if tx == nil {
        tx = getDatabase()
    }

    err := tx.Where("orders.id = ? AND external_user_id = ?", id, userID).
        Joins("LEFT JOIN delivery_informations ON delivery_informations.order_id = orders.id").Preload("DeliveryInformation").First(&order).Error
    if err != gorm.ErrRecordNotFound {
        return order, err
    }
    return order, nil
}
```

Actually when get pprof profiling the cpu usage is going high on this function.
[image]

Any suggestion how we must improve this call function to the query?

Thanks

Comment: I guess it's the query that's slow, and this is a sql (or whatever db you're using) problem, not a go, gorm or cpu problem.

Comment: what software picture that from ? is that can measure speed query

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should restrict the Preload

http://gorm.io/docs/preload.html

Comment: How do the restrict?

Comment: Check the “Preload with conditions”